# How to reinstall windows on a machine that has ubuntu on it now?

Tags: windows

I have a Dell i3252-10050BLK which was purchased with Windows 10 but a previous owner installed Ubuntu as a single-boot OS. There is no Windows partition on the drive.

The computer does not have a Windows label on the outside. I understand that the Windows Key is somehow created by the manufacturer for all computers of this model.

How do I reinstall Windows. I can create a Windows boot USB on another machine that has W10, but it sounds like I will need to key in the Windows Key, which I don't have.

Would the USB install somehow electronically detect that the machine has a built-in windows key?

Answer (score 1):

If your Dell i3252-10050BLK computer originally came with Windows 10 preinstalled, the Windows product key is embedded in the BIOS/UEFI firmware, so you won't need to enter it manually during the installation process.

To reinstall Windows 10 on your Dell computer, create a Windows 10 bootable USB drive on another computer that already has Windows 10, then boot your Dell computer from the USB drive. Windows should detect the embedded product key and activate your copy of Windows during the installation process.